# Bulk Google Datastore Queries using Java Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Could anyone please tell me how to perform Bulk/Multiple Datastore Queries in Java using Protocol Buffers.

Python has batch get and put. But how to in Java?

Comment: Its in the java docs. Put and get allow to pass a single key or an array.

Comment: it really depends on the framework you re using to access the datastore, are you planning to use Objectify (which i recommend), JDO, JPA?

Comment: I have already written a lot of code using Protocol Buffers...bcoz they are used in many examples by Google. But can't find a way to do that in this library. Re writing code is a nightmare!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cloud Client Library for Java Solved all my problems.

```
Datastore datastore;
DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("yourprojectID").setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream( new FileInputStream("localKeyFile.json"))).build();
dataStore = options.getService();

List<Key> queryKeys = new ArrayList<>();
Key key = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("SomeKind").newKey(1234L);
queryKeys.add(key);

// Add more keys if you need to the List..then start query!

Iterable<Key> keyIterable = queryKeys;
List<Entity> entities = null;

// Get Results

entities = dataStore.fetch(keyIterable);
```

See below links to Download Library and Docs.

Please vote it Up and Enjoy!

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/index.html

And the Docs-
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java